# Recyclerview notifyItemChanged doesn't work

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I try to update just one specific item after a "basic action" (like a tap on one item) in my recycler view, but the method notifyItemChanged seems to doesn't work as expected.

Actually, the method onBindViewHolder is correctly called, and datas that I want to change in my item is correctly done. BUT, I see nothing changing in my view. I don't understand why...

My code :

```
- MyFragment

private void initRecyclerView() {
    _recyclerView = (RecyclerView) _rootView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    _recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    _layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    _recyclerView.setLayoutManager(_layoutManager);

    _adapter = new MyAdapter(datas, this, getContext());
    _recyclerView.setAdapter(_adapter);
}
```

When an item is selected, I call "_adapter.update(position)" in my fragment. And so in my adapter I've this :

```
 -Adapter 

    public void updateItem(int position) {
        notifyItemChanged(position);
    }
```

After this call I can see that the method OnBindViewHolder is correctly call, but nothing is changed on the view :(

EDIT : code of onBindViewHolder :

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    MyOBject object = datas.get(position);
    holder.text1.setText(object.getValue1());
    holder.text2.setText(object.getValue2());

    if (object.getLastTimeItemClicked() != null && object.getLastTimeItemClicked().compareTo(object.getLastTimeNewContent()) > 0) { 
        Log.d("test", "item clicked, content changed")
        holder._backgroundItem.setCardBackgroundColor(_context.getResources().getColor(bgItemRead)); // I see this log after a tap on one item, so this code is working!
    }
}
```

EDIT 2 : I'm using tabs, maybe there is something to manage with that ?! (In each fragments linked to each tabs, there is a recycler view etc managed by a fragment)

Comment: try using notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: Could you please add more details on what you're trying to do? Say you've a collection of data, for example String tuplas (name, surname), let's say you've 10 of them, and your recycler view show only 3 at any time. If any item in your collection change, say name change from "MyName" to "YourName", then that's when you'll call notifyItemChanged(). Not on any UI change, but on the items change event. I'm sure you've clear that the recycler view separate the views from the data (item), and bind the data into the views on the fly; all to recycle the views of course.

Comment: It's not the solution. notifyItemChanged is done to update a specific item as I want. I want to work with this..

Comment: Could you share us onBindViewHolder() code? and also the code you use to update data before calling notifyItemChanged().

Comment: Alessio, in this basic case, I've 3 items in my recycler view I can see on my screen. When I tap on one item, I want to update some text and background item. But, It doesn't work as expect :/

Comment: Done @Thearith :)

Comment: When you call updateItem(position), are you modifying the arrayList which holds the MyOBject at mentioned position?

Comment: Yep :/ It's really strange because when I swipe between my tabs, and I tap on items, after few tests it works :o But when I restart the app, and tap on my first item for example, the view doesn't change...

Comment: Ok found the stupid problem... I defined a listener OnClickListener in static in my view holder. And I was using this adapter for severals fragments, so there was a problem of listener and this stupid problem happend :) It was for that the last fragment has item updated. Thx for your help.

Comment: @deveLost did you find the solution ? if so please share with us . I'm going through the same problem.